# About how many words of four letters are there in English?

Tags: orthography, dictionaries

I was trying to determine about how many words there are in English, with four letters.  (Ideally, excluding "s" plural, so cats and dogs would not be included.)

Does anyone have any concrete information on this such as an academic paper or perhaps some info from a dictionary or other reference I am unaware of?

(My investigation produced a number - I won't state it - which seemed wrong.)

Many fascinating related questions have come to mind: for example, "What's the most popular length of word in English?"  (You'd think we'd all intuitively know this as native speakers; I don't.)

Comment: 44,324, if you exclude the plurals.

Comment: Hey RIck!  that seems almost unbelievably high, what dictionary are you using?  Ps I meant "four" not "up to four" .. could be you were thinking 1,2,3,4 ?

Comment: Uh ... [tentatively] 12,916? ...

Comment: The official Scrabble word list has around 4000. But I can't separate out the plurals (on the other hand, the Scrabble word list has only around 1000 three-letter words, so most of them aren't plurals).

Comment: Orthographically? That is, not counting 'wind, n.' and 'wind, v.' as two words?

Comment: "What's the most popular length of word in English?" (You'd think we'd all intuitively know this as native speakers; I don't.)  There is the possibility that almost all most native speakers don't care very much.  If you found out that it was - say - 4.27 letters, how would this make your life better?

Comment: The upper bound, just based on spelling, is 26*26*26*26 = 456,976.  But of course that doesn't take into account the fact that most words must contain at least one vowel.

Comment: Hi there JEL -- that's a great point.  I guess, it would be interesting to know both ways.  The simpler way (wind counts as one) would be a good start.

Comment: Hi there Cargill - sorry, I don't follow you there? *"make your life better"* .. ?  Say I said to you, "What are some common letters, or uncommon letters, in English?"  As a native speaker, the answer to that would be absolutely inherently obvious to you. (Like say throwing and catching physics, or gender to speakers of gendered languages.)  It's interesting to me that "word lengths" is not such a quality.

Comment: hi @PeterShor - you should surely make that an answer.  It just seemed incredibly LOW to me, don't you agree??!  (And indeed, that does include plurals - cats, bees, dogs etc - and many crappy "scrabble words" or even just abbreviations/acronyms like aals, abye, acta, etc -  you could certainly say the real total is even less.)

Comment: Hi HotLicks; utterly unrelated to the question at hand, but if you're trying to figure out the count with vowels, as you probably know it's along the lines of 5.26.26.26 + 26.5.26.26 + .. and so on, the various combinations for one or more vowels.  However the "smart ass" way say game programmers do something like that is, you just *subtract the count of those that have no vowels*. (Which is trivial.) Natty, right?

Comment: @JoeBlow Remember to put @ before a name if you want someone to be notified of your comment. You left it out of your comments to JEL, Cargill, and HotLicks.

Comment: Hi Barmar.  I absolutely know that, and I absolutely never do it  :)